# SAP HANA: Temporary table not dropped automatically when connection pooling is enabled

Tags: sql, hana

I am using ADO.NET to connect SAP HANA database. I enable connection pooling in connection string like this: `Server=hana-db:30015;Pooling=true;Max Pool Size=50;Min Pool Size=5;UserID=JSmith;Password=secret`. But my problem is that, when I first connect to database and create a temporary table called #tbl, then disconnect without dropping #tbl. And when I reconnect to database, table #tbl still exists.
That doesn't happen when I set Pooling=false. So when Pooling=true, do I need manual drop temporary tables? Cause in MSSQL or Postgresql, temp tables dropped automatically when connection closed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in MSSQL it only drops the temp table on connection close when it's inside of a Stored Procedure. If your query is outside of a SP you will need to drop the temp tables yourself.

Comment: But It still not work if I use SP in SAP HANA.